# Declare enum as a class property (for child classes to define later?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I am making a game in Unity, and all of the player characters and enemy character's actions are determined by the value of enumerated type `moveState`. (The update function first queries the variable `myMoveState` and calls a switch/case function `MoveStateAction()` to decide what to do.) I want their parent class, `ActorClass`, to declare this enum so I don't have to declare it in every single script. Problem is, each actor has different possible `moveState`s. Whereas one enemy may be able to Charge, Return, Wait, and Search, maybe another enemy can Jump, Fall, Run, and Stop (these could be any state of action that needs to call a particular method). I want the child class to inherit the enum declaration and fill it with its own values.

I've tried to make the enum a property using `{ get; set; }` but the compiler reads "get" as the first enumeration and reads the semicolon as a syntax error. I've looked into using a generic property but I don't know if it's possible, let alone how to implement it. Microsoft's API guide is confusing.

And what if there's no way to declare an empty enum as a property? Is there a better way? I could use a different variable type just as well, but my code wouldn't be nearly as readable.  And I don't even think I could use a `typedef` alias to improve readability.

Here's what the generic code looks like for an enemy:

```
void Start () 
{
    myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    myDirection = Direction.S;
    myMoveState = moveState.START;
    currentSpeed = new Vector2(0, 0);
    previousSpeed= new Vector2(0, 0);
}

void FixedUpdate () 
{
    currentSpeed = myBody.velocity;
    previousSpeed *= dragScale;
    MoveStateAction();
    previousSpeed = currentSpeed;
    myBody.velocity = currentSpeed;
}
```

Comment: My first inclination would be to point you at `abstract` property declarations, but it's not clear to me what you want to do about the fact that each enemy can only have a subset of possible MoveState values. You might be able to do something funky with generics, but my gut tells me there's probably a better way to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: Show the code for how you're trying to declare the enum.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at your problem from a high-level point of view. You are trying to use inheritance but composition might be the better way to do it. Have a look at this example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#Example

Answer (score 0):

I think you are viewing the problem from an unfavorable angle. What are you going to do? You define a property in a parent class, inherit it by the child class and then say "Nah, lets kick out all the values and define new ones". But that is not the parent property anymore, nor is this the idea of inheritance.

So why do you want to make a property that can be inherited? Probably because you want all children to react the same way on the property. So the most favorable way probably would be to define an enum with all possible move states, and then block those you don't want for the specific class. For example, define a function CheckMoveState that returns None if MoveState is not one of the allowed states (for example, if it is Jump even though the create can only slither), and invoke this function each time a MoveState is passed to the class property in the setter.

So this is the definition in the parent class:

```
public enum MoveState
{
    None,
    Jump,
    Stop,
    Slither
}
```

And in the child class we have:

```
private MoveState CheckMoveState(MoveState myMoveState)
{
    if (myMoveState == MoveState.Slither || myMoveState == MoveState.Stop)
        return myMoveState;
    return MoveState.None;
}

private MoveState _currentMoveState = MoveState.None;

public MoveState CurrentMoveState
{
    get { return _currentMoveState; }
    set { _currentMoveState = CheckMoveState(value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking at what I've written so far I think your advice applies to... all of the things I thought inheritance would solve. Haha! Looks like I still have a lot to learn.

Perhaps I should just use ordinary protected variables and use the classes to inherit just the methods instead. Anyways, you've already given me an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Enum definitions are a bit special anyways. Think of them as types rather than as variables; an enum definition is not a list of values. Thus you can't "feed" them new values by run-time. It would be the same as defining an integer variable in the parent class and try to redefine it as string in the child class.

Answer (score 0):

**enums** are really not a posterchild for polymorphism; and making them *abstract* contradicts the essential reason why you "share" enums in the first place.

In essence, enums are glorified constants with some syntactic sugar around them. They are meant to be "shared"; thus there is **no point** in having an enum, but defer details to subclasses.

Besides: you are about to run into the "enum trap" anyway. It seems that you intend to write code that will do switching over enum values to determine what to do. And that is a *bad* idea. Because what you are doing there is a state machine in *disguise*. Instead, you should look into the reall OO answer to state machines ... and that is: implement one. Create some abstract base class that represents state (and then your subclasses are free to define "different" states, too); and then use a real state machine to deal with objects of that state class.